# Showing data in increments on map using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, symbology, classification

Let's say I have a feature class with `numerical values` say `age` greater than 0 and so on.

How can I show them classified them in such a way that these values are shown in increments of `20` on the map in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the increment value to an exact figure, such as 20, you will need to use the ***Manual Interval*** method.  You select the Manual Interval option then type in the values in the ***Upper value*** column.

[image]

Just note, if you want more classes this will be greyed out after you select Manual Interval and set Upper values.  You can add more classes by switching to Equal Interval temporarily, set the Classes value, then changing to Manual Interval. This preserves the number of class breaks but lets you change the Upper values.